# error in the operation of the -dev flag NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, npm-install

Can you tell me why when you use the syntax `npm i <package-name> --save - dev` The dependency is added to the list of common dependencies. But if you don't use abbreviations, everything works as intended `npm install <package-name> --save - dev`.

I was trying to add a development dependency using npm and encountered non-standard behavior when using abbreviations

Answer (score 0):

In the Node Package Manager, or NPM, the command to save a dependency as a development one is `--save-dev` rather than `--save - dev`. Try the same command with `npm i <package-name> --save-dev` and see if you get a different result.

Comment: Thank you, now everything is working as it should

Comment: No problem! Welcome to StackOverflow! If you like an answer, make sure you mark it as the correct one so passing programmers will no that your query is solved.